# SAS counting sum of columns with a loop

Tags: sas

I need to run trough 10 columns (100obs) (score1-score10) and sum up each row to a final score. I created an additional variable "Fscore" but for some reason it doesn't  stop counting at the end of the row, and so if my first row sum is 50, and second is 20, the Fscore for row 2 will be 70.
how can I count then row by row? => so the Fscore for row 1 =50, 2=20 (and not 70) and so on..

```
data PAR12;set PAR11;
    array score{*} score1-score10;
    DO i=1 to dim(score);
    if score[i]=10 then Fscore+10;
    else Fscore+0;
    END; 
    drop i;
    run;
```

Comment: I only have 2 score types = 10 and 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method of summation (Fscore+10) without an equal results in an implicit retain statement being added which is why the value is held over. You could add a `Fscore=0` before your do loop, as below or use a direct sum function demonstrated with the `Fscore2=sum(of score(*))` in the data.

```
data PAR12;
set PAR11;
array score{*} score1-score10;
Fscore=0;
DO i=1 to dim(score);
   if score[i]=10 then Fscore+10;
   else Fscore+0; *This isn't required either;
END; 
Fscore2=sum(of score(*)); *no do loop required;
drop i;
run;
```

EDIT: 
Considering @Joe's comments this would be one other way to accomplish it via a do loop.

```
data PAR12;
set PAR11;
array score{*} score1-score10;
DO i=1 to dim(score);
  FScore=Fscore+score(i);
END; 
Fscore2=sum(of score(*)); *no do loop required;
drop i;
run;
```

Comment: I would argue that `x+y;` is inappropriate when it's not desired to be retained, even if it does work when you reset it to zero each time.  It's odd to use a syntax that is meant for one purpose in an entirely different way.

Comment: That would be a matter of convention?

Comment: Sure, but i'd argue it's a good convention.  Indenting code and splitting it across lines is also a matter of convention.